# iOS Share Extension Dynamic Javascript

Tags: ios8, xcode6, ios-app-extension

I am developing a share extension for iOS 8 and it seem like i can run javascript code on page to grab some information like image urls, etc.

But on the apple document it says that javascript code must be inside a .js file but my javascript code is coming from server and it is dynamic.

Is it possible to run javascript i downloaded from server or can I change js file contents everytime I need to use it?

Thanks

Edit
It seems like it is impossible to change the file.
And if your javascript making asynchronous call the **loadItemForTypeIdentifier: options: completionHandler:** call is not grabing the end value of async call.

Comment: Is it possible to run javascript i downloaded from server or can I change js file contents every time I need to use it?

Comment: Did you get any answer for above ?